# Types of permutations - official naming?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I've seen some people describe the $n^r$ permutation formula (where you can use the same option more than once) as "Permutation with Repetition". Yet some others describe the $$\frac{n!}{(n - r)! k!}$$ 
(where you have an option repeated more than once) as "Permutation with Repetition".

For the second one, I'm referring to a scenario like this: https://www.ck12.org/probability/permutations-with-repetition/lesson/Permutations-with-Repetition-BSC-PST/

What exactly is the common/standard way to name these $2$ formulas/scenarios?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Did you mean two write $\frac{n!}{r!(n - r)!}$ or $\frac{n!}{(n - r)!}$ rather than $\frac{n!}{(n - r)!k!}$?

Comment: @N. F. Taussig For the second one, I'm referring to a scenario like this: https://www.ck12.org/probability/permutations-with-repetition/lesson/Permutations-with-Repetition-BSC-PST/

Comment: The $n^r$ formula is for "**permutations with repetition**" whereas the formula $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{l}m_i\right)!/\left(\prod_{i=1}^{l} m_i!\right)$ is for "**permutations of multisets**". See the respective subheadings [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) for more details.